# Utilizar Firebase sin Internet

Tags: firebase

Buenas les hago otra consultar por que se que puedo contar con la ayuda de ustedes.

He estado empezando a utilizar Firebase razón por la cual se me presentan algunas dudas. Si Firebase está hecho para utilizarse sin internet, entonces como hago para confirmar si se ejecuta una "acción", por ejemplo:

```
ref.child(user.getUid()).child("Animales").child(child.child("id").getValue(String.class)).removeValue();
```

Es una referencia a un nodo que quiero eliminar, pero necesito realizar otra "accion" cuando se confirme ésta. Si uso:

```
ref.child(user.getUid()).child("Animales").child(child.child("id").getValue(String.class)).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener()...
```

ó

```
ref.child(user.getUid()).child("Animales").child(child.child("id").getValue(String.class)).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener()..
```

Me sirven a la perfección, pero solo si tengo conexión a internet. De paso mi persistencia de disco está funcionando bien.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder habilitar está opción debes de esperar el evento [`onDisconnect()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect?hl=es-419):

```
var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    alert("connected");
  } else {
    alert("not connected");
  }
});
```

Puedes conseguir información más precisa en [este enlace](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities?hl=es-419) en la documentación de Firebase.